# when using rsync --copy-links, rsync ignores symlink name changes

Tags: linux, sync, rsync, symbolic-link

We're using symlinks to create "virtual" folder/file trees using content from all over the disk. In essence we have a mess and a script will create an organized file tree by creating symlinks to those original unorganized files while slugging the file names, etc. 
Once this is done we want to sync this "virtual" file tree to a remote server so we use rsync with the `--copy-links` param.

The problem we encounter is that rsync completely ignores any changes in symlink names. So for example:

```
mkdir export # make a dir for export
ln -s /file.jpg export/fileLink.jpg # create a link to file.jpg
rsync --copy-links -avzhs --delete export/ /tmp/rsyncExport # rsync with an export dir
ls /tmp/rsyncExport/
fileLink.jpg
# we find our file (not a symlink) with the symlink name.
```

So far so good, but if we change the link name and re-sync :

```
rm export/fileLink.jpg
ln -s /file.jpg export/fileLink2.jpg # create a link to file.jpg but with another name
rsync --copy-links -avzhs --delete export/ /tmp/rsyncExport # rsync again
ls /tmp/rsyncExport/
fileLink.jpg
# we find our file (not a symlink) with the old symlink name and not the new one.
```

Obviously rsync "follows" the link and the file hasn't changed so it just moves on ignoring the fact that the link is different.

Is there any way to fix the behavior above?

Thanks for your help.